# How can I listen in my client service to a newly registered service in the Eureka server?Listen to Eureka Server events

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a service 'A' which is being registered with the Eureka server, and I would like the Eureka server to notify that service every time a new service is registered within Eureka.
**Is there any way of doing it?**

Comment: apparently related (according to a non-answer posted as an answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834706/listening-to-eureka-events/76489616

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you poll the registry regularly from the app that needs to know?

Failing that I don't believe there's a built in feature with Eureka to push this kind of alert. You could achieve it though by customising the Eureka project and reacting to the registration. According to similar discussions elsewhere, EurekaInstanceRenewedEvent that is fired when a new instance first heartbeats is a reliable event to work around. I'm not sure how quickly you need to be notified.

Comment: I would like to have it in the other way, I mean, the server (Eureka server) notifies all listening clients. And the other thing is I'm not the owner (developer) of the Eureka server deployed, so I can't add any change there :(.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement an event listener for Eureka server events. Start by creating a class that implements the `ApplicationListener` interface and specifies the event type you want to listen for. For example, if you want to listen for registration events, you can implement `ApplicationListener < EurekaInstanceRegisteredEvent>.`

Then, implement the event handling logic by overriding the `onApplicationEvent` method in your listener class to handle the event. This method will be called when the specified event occurs. You can access relevant information from the event object and perform any desired actions, such as logging, updating a database, or notifying other components.

Comment: That event is available on the registry side (eureka server), only. So, it cannot be used on the client side.